# In Java, how can I return two different types based on an argument?

Tags: java, spring

Say that I have a method like this:

```
public AbstractContractApplication acceptOffer(AcceptedOfferDto dto)
{
    // various application stuff
    Contract contract; // deeply integrated into the above code
    return processedApplication;  // also deeply integrated into the above code 
}
```

I would like to refactor my method to sometimes return `contract` instead of `processedApplication` based on an argument provided in the `AcceptedOfferDto`. Ideally something like this:

```
if (AcceptedOfferDto.getReturnConfig() == 1){
return contract;
}

else {
return processedApplication; 
}
```

Is there a clean way to do this which does not involve copy and pasting the bulk of the code in the function or refactoring a large block of extremely important business logic?

The current line of thinking is to create a class that contains instances of both objects and just select the correct value from that. What other options might be available?

Comment: What is the type of `processedApplication`? What does it has in common with the `Contract` class?

Comment: @VictorStafusa they both are created with some of the same information and then they are used together to later create other objects.

Comment: Which same information? This completely changes what would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @VictorStafusa the variables in the AcceptOfferDto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that `Contract` and `AbstractContractApplication` have nothing useful in common to rely on polimorphism and you can't refactor too much things, you could use this:

```
public interface EitherOne<A, B> {
    public default boolean isA() { return false; }
    public default boolean isB() { return false; }
    public default A getA() { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
    public default B getB() { throw new IllegalStateException(); }

    public static <A, B> EitherOne<A, B> a(A a) {
        return new EitherOne<>() {
            @Override public boolean isA() { return true; }
            @Override public boolean getA() { return a; }
        };
    }

    public static <A, B> EitherOne<A, B> b(B b) {
        return new EitherOne<>() {
            @Override public boolean isB() { return true; }
            @Override public boolean getB() { return b; }
        };
    }
}
```

I really don't recommend anyone using this. It should be used only as a quick and dirty escape hatch hack for complicated situations.

Then, you can try this:

```
public EitherOne<Contract, AbstractContractApplication> acceptOffer(AcceptedOfferDto dto) {
    // various application stuff
    AbstractContractApplication processedApplication = ...;
    Contract contract = ...; // deeply integrated into the above code
    if (AcceptedOfferDto.getReturnConfig() == 1) return EitherOne.a(contract);
    return EitherOne.b(processedApplication);  // also deeply integrated into the above code 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is not meant as a permanent solution, just a proof of concept.

Answer (score -1):

Use Polymorphism.
The type of `contract` (Contract) and `processedApplication` (?) must be subtypes of `AbstractContractApplication`.